# JS: calling functions via buttons does not work anymore, if page is updated without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, web

I want to write a program with one html page, which i can update and fill with different elements via javascript with one button that stays the same in every version, which displays a modalBox. I made a very basic version of this: One page, that is filled with two buttons (next and last) for navigating through the pages and one to display the modal. In addition, i added a number, which is incremented oder decremented accordingly, when you click through the updated versions of the page.

```js
var counter = 1;

function setUp(){
    var c = document.getElementById("container");
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.setAttribute("id", "main");
    d.innerHTML = counter;

    var nxt = document.createElement("button");
    var bck = document.createElement("button");
    var modalBtn = document.createElement("button");

    nxt.innerText = ">";
    bck.innerText = "<";
    modalBtn.innerText="Show Modal";

    nxt.setAttribute("onclick","nextPage()");
    bck.setAttribute("onclick","lastPage()");
    modalBtn.setAttribute("onclick","showModal()");

    d.appendChild(bck);
    c.appendChild(d);
    d.appendChild(nxt);
    d.appendChild(modalBtn);
}
function showModal(){
    var m = document.getElementById("modal");
    m.style.display = "block";
}
function closeModal(){
    var m = document.getElementById("modal");
    m.style.display = "none";
}
function nextPage(){
    var c = document.getElementById("container");
    c.innerHTML="";
    counter++;
    setUp();
}
function lastPage(){
    var c = document.getElementById("container");
    c.innerHTML="";
    counter--;
    setUp();
}

setUp();
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#modal{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;

}
#main{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tryout.css">
    <script src="tryout.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
    <div id="modal"><button id="closeButton" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is: on onload, the modal button works fine (on click, the modal is displayed). As soon as i update (not reloading!) the page via the next- or back button, the modal button stops working (Error-message says the type of modalbutton is null). I have no clue why, because to my knowledge, the buttons are reinitiated by clicking on the next or back button (because the setUp()-function is called in the functions triggered by the buttons). As soon as I reload the page via the reload-button, it is working until i use one of the next and back buttons.
I am new to js, it's probable that I'm missing sth. obvious here :) Many Thanks!

Comment: `#modal` is inside `#container` move it outside the container `<div id="modal"><button id="closeButton" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button></div><div id="container"></div>`

Comment: @Sakil Thanks :) That was even easier to fix than expected...

Answer (score 0):

On the "nextPage" and "lastPage" function , you're just removing the whole content (including the modal) from the div which associated **container** class.
That's why when you calling the "showModal" function , there is no element with **modal** id on the DOM. That's why its saying null.

you can follow what Sakil said on the comment or, in your both(nextPage & lastPage) functions,you can just remove the div with id **main** and add it later on "setUp" function.
I'm adding some code snippet below, hope it will help;

```
    function nextPage() {

        //grab the div with "main" id
        let main = document.getElementById("main");

        //remove it from document
        main.remove();

        counter++;

        //add it again; what you're doing actually.
        setUp();
      }

   function lastPage() {
       
        //grab the div with "main" id
        let main = document.getElementById("main");

        //remove it from document
        main.remove();

        counter--;

        //add it again; what you're doing actually.
        setUp();
      }
```

of course you should refactor the code base, cause there is lot more copy-pasting staff present, but I'm leaving that up to you.